# How to "model" with blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I watched this video

and you see the mech is modeled out of iron blocks and clay. and my question is how does the command block do it? I it armor stands? If so how do do it quickly?

Please answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model itself is not created using commands, but a custom resource pack that it has you download. Inside the resource pack are the files for the models:

[image: Model files]

Without the resource pack, the mech is just a diamond hoe:

[image: Diamond hoe mech]

You can create them by hand ([see this wiki page on model format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Model)), but to do it "quickly" you'll likely want to use a tool.

The mech model file was created using [BDCraft Cubik PRO](http://bdcraft.net/cubik-pro), but it's not free. Two good free alternatives are [MrCrayfish's Model Creator](http://mrcrayfish.com/tools?id=mc) and [opl's Model Creator](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/2146545-opls-model-creator-free-3d-model-editor).